# coding print statements for spacing between lines

Tags: syntax, formatting, statements, redundancy

Like everyone, we all like clean lines of code, reducing the total number of lines we must read through. In dressing up the printed statements I receive in my code, I would like to use 3x print statements between the result and a line separating the answer from the next section of the program.

The relevant part of my code is as follows:

```
print()
print("Below is the answer you selected.")
print()
print(programSelect)

print() #How do I do something like 3 * print()
print(4 * "===")
```

As the hash tag says, how would I code 3x print statements in one statement like 3 * print()? Or is this simply not possible, and I must resign myself to typing out three print() statements?

Comment: If you really do have that much formatted output going on, you could define your own set of higher level print functions that accept other arguments that assist with the formatting. Bit that said, if you want three blank lines, it's simple to do in one, clear print statement.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem is thus:

print(3 * "\n")

This, when followed by print(4 * "   ====") yields the following

"something long and meaningless for this example"

====   ====   ====   ====

Which is what I wanted to get. I think the comment from Lurker sent me on my way to discovering the solution.